# Kerning between 'V' and '.'

Tags: fonts, kerning

The canonical font used in LaTeX does not seem to implement any special kerning between letters and dots, possibly resulting in too much space (say, for the combinations "V." or "T.") in my opinion.
Is there a font that implements kerning for that combination? Is there some other way to uniformly implement it (instead of in a case by case basis)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, many other fonts do kern these combinations. Check [the catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). For example Charter (`\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`) or Garamond (`\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`: you will probably have to install the font from CTAN) or Minion Pro (`\usepackage{MinionPro}`: you will have to buy the font and then follow the instructions on CTAN for installing the TeX support).